# High accuracy measures when using pretrained embedding layer in Python

Tags: python, keras, nlp

I am trying to implement a pretrained embedding layer into my generative model using GloVe.

Into the model I feed sequences of 50 (X) items pulled from a text, and it is to predict the 51. word (y) in the text.

I reach an accuracy of 0.99 already when the model only has trained for 1/100 iterations. What can be the issue?

```
# create a weight matrix for words in training docs
embedding_matrix = zeros((vocab_size, 100))
for word, i in tokenizer.word_index.items():
embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
if embedding_vector is not None:
    embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

 # define model
 model = Sequential() #assigning the sequential function to a model
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 100, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=seq_length, trainable = False)) #defining embedding layer size
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True)) #adding layer of nodes
model.add(LSTM(100))  #adding layer of nodes
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu')) #specifying the structure of the hidden layer, recu is an argument of a rectified linear unit. 
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')) #using the softmax function to creating probabilities
print(model.summary())
# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit the model
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=128, epochs=100, verbose=1)
```

Link to github: https://github.com/KiriKoppelgaard/Generative_model 
commit from  Nov 14, 2018

Comment: What is the size of the corpus your are training on? Given the accuracy achieved you are very likely over-fitting the model due to a small dataset.

Comment: Is it the case that one sample may belong to multiple classes, i.e. be multiple words? I don't guess so.

Comment: I have around 500000 sequences the model is trained on, so I suspect it is not overfitting, but maybe I did not implement the embedding layer correctly.

Comment: I am not sure I entirely get, what you are asking @today

Comment: I am reffereing to the type of the model and the loss function you have used: if it is a single-label classification task (i.e. each sample has only one label and not mutiple label) it must be `categorical_crossentropy` instead.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll just check if that helps. It is multiple labels we use @today